# FireStore Transaction: Transaction is not being atomic

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to set some data at one path and then trying to delete data from another once the earlier set operation succeeds. For the I'm using FireStore transactions. The following is the code.

```
const unapprovedItemRef = admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("unapproved")
  .doc(id);

return admin.firestore().runTransaction(transaction =>
  transaction
    .get(unapprovedItemRef)
    .then(unapprovedItemSnapshot => {
      const item = unapprovedItemSnapshot.data();
      if (!item) {
        throw new Error("No such item");
      }

      const data = {
        added_on: new Date()
      };

      const dataRef = admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("data")
        .doc('saved');

      return transaction.set(dataRef, data);
    })
    .then(() => transaction.delete(unapprovedRef)) // deliberate error
    .then(() =>
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "Success"
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "Failed",
        error: err.message
      })
    )
```

The problem is, `delete` operation of the transaction is failing (because I deliberately introduced a bug in it) but still the `set` operation is succeeding when it should also fail as it is only one half of logical transaction.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you attached your own `.catch` block, Firestore doesn't know that your transaction failed. Your catch block converts `throw new Error("No such item")` into a successful Promise, which Firestore uses to commit your transaction.

Furthermore, the `transaction.delete()` line never gets executed, since the previous block failed. If you move this line just after the catch block, it should also cause the transaction to fail.